# Does anyone know much about this Fibonacci-like sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

I recently came across this sequence which looks quite similar to the Fibonacci numbers.

Let $a_0 = 0 \ $ and $a_1 = 1$, then define $a_n := (a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}) \bmod n$. This is given by [$A079777$](https://oeis.org/A079777) in the OEIS.

The first few terms are given below

$$a_2 = (1 + 0) \bmod 2 = 1$$
$$a_3 = (1 + 1) \bmod 3 = 2$$
$$a_4 = (2 + 1) \bmod 4 = 3$$
$$a_5 = (3 + 2) \bmod 5 = 0$$
$$a_6 = (0 + 3) \bmod 6 = 3$$
$$a_7 = (3 + 0) \bmod 7 = 3$$

This is essentially the Fibonacci sequence with an extra modulus operation, but the moduli change value each term, hence this is different from the sequence of Fibonacci numbers$\bmod N$.

Although I don't have any meaningful use of this sequence, I am curious to learn more about it. However, despite the sequence's simple definition and connection to the Fibonacci numbers, I'm yet to find much relevant information online.

---

One interesting thing I looked at is the indices $n$ such that $a_n = 0$, the first few being

$$0, \ 5, \ 9, \ 12, \ 24, \ 45, \ 60, \ 65, \ 179, \ ...$$

This is sequence [$A073853$](https://oeis.org/A073853) in the OEIS, and its graph suggests that the terms grow exponentially. I managed to compute a new term in this sequence using some C code, and I believe that there are infinitely many.

Apart from the OEIS, I haven't found anything online regarding these two sequences as mentioned previously. I was a bit surprised at this considering their simplicity, so if anyone knows anything more about these sequences, or can provide links to other sources, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: If there were relevant papers, chances are they'd already be referenced in OEIS. Doesn't prove there aren't any, of course.

Comment: A heuristic for A073853's growth rate: if these numbers were chosen "at random" then $a_n$ has probability 1/n of being zero, so there should be about $\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n \approx \log(N)$ zero values below $N$, giving an exponential growth rate as you've observed.

Comment: Also it's a bit strange that the sequence of zeros (A073853) has a lower number than the original Fibonacci-esque sequence (A079777), and therefore predates it.

Comment: That is quite strange, especially seen as the gap between the two is several thousand. I did actually have that same heuristic for $A073853$'s growth rate, I just wonder if any more information is known on these sequences. The only decent thing I've managed to prove so far is that $$a_{n+k} = F_{k+1}a_n + F_k a_{n - 1} - p_k n - q_k$$ if the RHS $\ge 0$, where $$p_k = F_{k+2} - 1, \ \text{and} \ q_k = F_{k+4} - (k+3).$$ This is most useful when the values $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ are quite close to $n$ itself.